# Finding all complex roots of an equation with exponentials.

Tags: roots

I know that

$$ (-1)^x + 2^x - 2 x - 1 = 0 $$

has a single real root $(x =3)$ and an infinite number of complex roots whose real part appears often negative. Don't the complex roots also have their conjugates as solutions(roots)?

Even I am unable to  readily plot its left hand side to be able to see that a wavy graph should appear not cutting negative x-axis.  Appreciate an answer about   cause of this phenomenon and its remedy.